# Playing video in AIR app built for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I'm building an app that plays video in AIR for Android.

when I package the video into the apk and set the source like this:

```
FLVPlayback(player).source = "clip.mov";
```

It loads and plays, but as per [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4075389#4075389) discussion, it's very jerky, and I'm trying to implement the suggested solution of loading the video from the DCIM folder instead of packaging it with in the apk.

When I put the video into the DCIM folder (manually) and then call this:

```
FLVPlayback(player).source = File.userDirectory.nativePath + "/DCIM/clip.mov";
```

Nothing happens (it reports the path correctly as /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/clip.mov, which I can see is sitting in the correct place on the device's file system).

I seems like some sort of permission thing, but I'm not sure what permission I'd need to set for this to function correctly.  What's the correct methodology for loading video from the file system into FLVPlayback component that is slated to run in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out... actually not at all obvious, so, I'll leave this here as the answer in case it helps someone else.

For some reason, passing the literal path to the source property doesn't work, and instead, you need to create a File object out of the path and then pass that object's url property to source, so, it all comes together like this:

```
var fileLoc:String = File.userDirectory.nativePath+ "/DCIM/clip.mov";

var f:File = new File(fileLoc);

FLVPlayback(player).source = f.url;
```

As it happens, it's still totally jerky playback, so, I'm now going to try to see if building it as a native Android app and using the native video player is the solution, or if the problem is my .mov file.